# Remove only files inside directory and subdirectory

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Remove only files inside directory and subdirectory

Not the directory
Not the subdirectory

only want to delete the files inside directory and subdirectory

Answer (score 2):

- To remove **all** the files under `dir/subdir/file` (both `dir/subdir/file` and `dir/subdir/subsubdir/file` will be removed):

```sh
find dir/subdir -type f -delete
```

- To remove files at most one level below `dir/subdir` (this removes `dir/subdir/file` but not `dir/subdir/subsubdir/file`):

```sh
find dir/subdir -maxdepth 1 -type f -delete
```

- To remove `dir/file` and `dir/subdir/file` but not `dir/subdir/subsubdir/file`:

```sh
find dir dir/subdir -maxdepth 1 -type f -delete
```